# Which database to choose for storing and reading the stats?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, influxdb, high-load

Which database to choose for storing and reading events or logs (i.e. ad requests, impressions, etc..)?

Approximately 30 new entries per second. Chance growth. It is therefore necessary flexible scaling.

Elasticsearch? InfluxDB? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

events or logs ? => **Elasticsearch**

https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch:

> Elasticsearch builds distributed capabilities on top of Apache Lucene
>   to provide the most powerful full- text search capabilities available.

As far as I know,  you can't write strings into InfluxDB.
It is a timeseries DB with math functions on numbers (min/max/average/last/...).
So it can't works with text

Comment: InfluxDB can store strings up to 64KB, as well as floats, ints, and booleans.

Answer (score 0):

InfluxDB is a reasonable solution for your needs, and it handles text just fine. There are no text-based functions, however, only math functions. That said, for only 30 points per second it might be overkill. You don't need the performance capabilities of InfluxDB, so a more mature solution might fit your use case better.

Comment: Thank you. Recommend anything?

Comment: Elasticsearch, Splunk, or a well-turned Postgres installation are what I'd try. It's all a matter of finding the right balance between price, utility, and maintenance.